# Export Google Maps Route to KML/GPX

Tags: google-maps, export, routing

Since Google pulled the plug on Google Maps Classic, I'm reluctantly moving to its [Google Maps New](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/) application.

However, I didn't find how to export a route to a GPX or KML file so it can be copied onto my smartphone.

Can it do this? If not, is there a third-party solution?

Comment: Still worked in USA in Jan 2019. Needed only the URL from my Google map; file loaded into my Garmin GPS; all points present and accounted for.

Comment: Super simple with https://mapstogpx.com/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

GPS Visualizer will take a Google Map route (url) and convert to .gpx

> "You can ignore most the options, just select Gpx and  paste the
> Google Maps URL into the box labelled “provide the URL of a file on
> the Web” and then press the Convert button"

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input

For details, see [How to plan a route in Google Maps and export it to Gpx / your phone.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160329131756/http://bedsforcyclists.co.uk/articles/2014/04/13/how-to-plan-a-route-in-google-maps-and-export-it-to-gpx-your-phone/)

Comment: Seems good still in 2017, even though I've been fiddling with waypoints/destinations in the URL

Comment: This isn't working for me, GPSvisualizer says "file not found".  I've tried copying the full URL and also the shortened URL from the share button.

Comment: Not working for me either, says: "Due to dramatic reductions in Google's quotas, you can no longer convert Google directions URLs unless you supply your own API key.  See http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/misc/google_api_keys.html for more information."

Comment: Yes google changed the terms on 11th June 2018. https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/important-updates and the 16th July 2018 is the active date for this, you are seeing the result of the changes.

Comment: As of July 2018, gpsvisualizer requires you to supply your own API key

Answer (score 18):

To export a route to KML you'll have to use [Google MyMaps](http://google.com/mymaps).

- add a route to new or existing layer
- drag and drop the route to suit your needs
- Open the maps options menue (3 dots above the layers)
- Export to KML

You can then use any service to convert the KML to GPX. I prefer [GPSies](http://www.gpsies.com/convert.do). (edit: now acquired by [AllTrails](https://www.alltrails.com/converter/?referrer=gpsies))

Comment: The export to KML is no longer possible in Switzerland in the options menue.

Comment: Export to KML is still possible from a German account, including routes in Switzerland. (as of 2017-11-20).

Comment: Option seems to be removed also in Finland.

Comment: Still working on an Irish account. Just to be clear, it is in the three dots menu of the map title, not not the layers own three dots.

Comment: GPSies was acquired. New URL is https://www.alltrails.com/converter

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me (example for biking route, can also be used for car route):

- Open http://google.com/mymaps
- Create a new map
- Click "Draw A Line Icon" and select "Add Biking Route" (a new routelayer will be created)
- Select your starting point "A" with cursor on map and start drawing (single click to fix waypoints)
- Double click to set "Endpoint B"
- Adjust while dragging route until ok.
- Rename the layer (and optionally map)
- Click on 3 vertical dots (of map) and "Export to KML/KMZ"
- Select only the route layer (uncheck other options)
- Download KMZ
- Convert KMZ using https://www.alltrails.com/converter/
- Open KMZ
- Convert to Track/Route
- Download as GPX track
- Click "Convert File"

Optional for BikeGPX:

- Import GPX file into https://bikegpx.com/
- Select "Upload File"
- Drag GPX
- Save route (do not share)
- Scan QR code with BikeGPX app on Android

Answer (score 2):

I think that in the current version of G Maps (in desktop, May 2018), you can click on "my timeline" at the left sidebar which appears when you click on the three-bar menu symbol at left of the search bar.  Then your timeline appears in a separate tab, where you can select a day with the date timeline at upper left to find the route or timeline for that day.  then if you go to the settings gear symbol at lower right, there is an option to "export this day to KML".  Is that helpful?  I use this all the time to transfer field visits to QGIS or google earth and compare to spatial data on soils, climate, google earth images that give me a better overall view of the landscape versus what one sees walking or driving, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this tool I’m tinkering with building. It will give you waypoints and routes for google maps directions:

http://hardkjarni.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/converting-google-maps-directions-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Export a map

You can export and download an entire map or just some information on it. That way, you can import and see your geographical data in other apps. For example, on a map with cross-country driving directions and restaurants along the way, download just the directions so you can visualize it in Google Earth.

Export your map's data
Click the map menu button  in the left panel.
Select Export as KMZ.
Choose the layer you want to export, or click Entire map. 
[Optional] To export as network link, check the box.
Click Export.
Note: A KMZ map link updates about every 10 minutes. If you see a delay in updates, check back shortly.

Export the data of a map shared with you
Sometimes, the owner of a map may provide view-only access. This means you can’t edit the map by adding places or layers, but you can still export the map’s data.

In the legend, click the share button  .
Select Download KMZ.
Choose the layer you want to export, or click Entire map.
[Optional] To export as network link, check the box.
Click Export.
More info about exporting
Keep data up-to-date with network links

Answer (score 0):

I have created an app that is able to download a GPX file from Google Maps directions. Afterthat you can send this file to a GPS device or share it using Whatsapp, GMail, ...
It's possible to download a GPX file from other sources like Strava or Wikiloc.
This is the app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spark71.traxapp

You can watch this videos before to use it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KcXBbV6L9iA&list=PLzd7QZILvgy5OSJHSBikB5sHFMQOZ1im1

Answer (score 0):

Copy the link from Google Maps to the https://mapstogpx.com/ .