# App to save GIS-friendly route

Tags: shapefile, routing, software-recommendations, android

I have a 3G and location ready Android device. I am looking for an app which will allow me to save a route in KML or shapefile format. The reason I am OK with KML is that I know that this is convertible to shapefile via ArcGIS toolbox.

So far I have only found MapInr which appears only able to save waypoints and this won't do. I feel like this functionality should exist and be readily available since we have ancient garmin GPS devices perfectly capable of doing this. The only downside is that they require custom basemaps.

What app could be used so I can then upload my route as a shapefile and use it?

Comment: from http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152593/59 it appears this might work http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input

Answer (score 1):

CellViz is designed to collect cell signal data attached to GPS points, and then you can email yourself the results (includes a CSV and KML file):
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cellviz.android

I think this should accomplish what's your looking for. Full disclaimer, I'm the author.

Another option is MyTracks, which Google said they are shutting down but still remains active:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.maps.mytracks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any run tracking apps? They would post it to an online site and you might find one with a Shape or KML download.

For example, mapmyfitness [says it has an option](https://support.mapmyfitness.com/hc/en-us/articles/200896030-Workout-Features) to export as KML.

Not a one-stop solution, but since you're talking about loading into ArcGIS anyway, I figure there's not a lot of difference.